# How can I change the structure format of an xml file?

Tags: xml, data-conversion

I have an large set of xml files and I want to change its format a bit. How can i do that?

here is my problam: for example  I have following:

```
<annotation>
<folder>New1</folder>
<filename>0000065.jpg</filename>
<path>C:\Users\farshad\Desktop\New1\0000065.jpg</path>
<source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
</source>
<size>
    <width>710</width>
    <height>287</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>car</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>132</xmin>
        <ymin>47</ymin>
        <xmax>574</xmax>
        <ymax>283</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>
```

and I want to change it to following format:

```
<annotation>
<folder>New1</folder>
<filename>0000065.jpg</filename>
<source>
<database>OXFORD-IIIT Pet Dataset</database>
<annotation>OXIIIT</annotation>
<image>flickr</image>
</source>
<size>
    <width>710</width>
    <height>287</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>car</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <occluded>0</occluded>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>132</xmin>
        <ymin>47</ymin>
        <xmax>574</xmax>
        <ymax>283</ymax>
    </bndbox>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
</object>
</annotation>
```

thanks a lot for any recommendation.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: Too many options depending on your available skills and tooling (eg. XSLT, any common language has XML parsers/writers). We can help you with details of using a tool, but [SO] doesn't do tool recommendations.

Comment: You should create a program by using which language do you know and do it yourself and this time when you wrote some code we can help you if you have errors.

Comment: I use python. Is there such tools in python?

Comment: Yeh its best just do it yourself and we can help you when you have errors

Comment: Or i show an example to get started

Comment: could you please show me an example dear Azhy?

Comment: Yes i have an easy idea to do that, but a question are all of them have the same formatting as you said you want to change or they are different?

Comment: I have a set of 2000 xml file correspond to 2000 image files (jpg) and each of theis xml file has its own xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax as coordinates of rectangle box.

Comment: @Farshad Do you want just add some other elements or you want delete some spaces before tags i dont understood.

Comment: for example i want to delete :
<path>C:\Users\farshad\Desktop\New1\0000065.jpg</path>
     from first xml and then add      
   <annotation>OXIIIT</annotation>
   <image>flickr</image> 
      after tag <dataset>.

also i want to transfer :
<difficult>0</difficult>    
    in first xml to the end line of file before    </object>   . So i will have the second xml.

Comment: Ok just wait i am do it using regex although theres some other ways to do that but may spend some time

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Azhy.

Comment: I don't think it's quite fair to mark this as a duplicate of a question that specifically asks for a Python solution, when this question is open to other approaches. The usual way of tackling this kind of transformation is to use XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to this kind of transformation is to use XSLT. I'm not going to write the code for you, and I wouldn't suggest using XSLT without first reading up on the basic concepts of the language, but in outline:

Define a rule for processing the annotation element, which processes all its children using the relevant rules:

```
<xsl:template match="annotation">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Define a default rule for processing the children of annotation, which is to copy them unchanged:

```
<xsl:template match="annotation/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Define a rule for deleting the `<path>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="path"/>
```

Define a rule for transforming the `<source>` element. I don't know what your logic is for this bit so I'll leave it unfinished:

```
<xsl:template match="source">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

There's a wide choice of XSLT processors available. Many of them (including the default processor for Python) only support XSLT 1.0, which is quite adequate for a simple transformation like this. Later you'll come across more complex transformations that need XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, so you may want to start with a processor that has that capability.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found something and i am sorry for the time because i read something about **Regular Expressions** which says we cannot use **RE** with **Maliformed Languages** like XML or HTML, they hardly says that we cannot use these two things together, so i decided to do it by using **DOM** packages or xml parser packsges, so now let's get started:-

i created a code for you which you should firstly do some changes to it and after that use it, and i **hardly** suggest you to firstly use this program with some examples to learn using it first, i am not saying my code is invalid, but you said it's a large amount of files so i don't want to spend all of them wrongly, just first test it to learn how to use it easily.

> Some Notes:-

**1 - `TagIndex`es is the index of tag name, which sometimes there are two elements with same name so use it when you it happens, it came from ** `*.getElementsByTagName(...)[tagIndex]`.**

**2 - Firstly test it on some examples to learn using it, also you can dont do it but i don't want to loose all of your data because of some small errors, also don't scare i dont say my code has errors and you can read it yourself but this warning is because of loosing your data.**

**3 - Don't forget to set the containing folder.**

**4 - I wanted to add a future for adding elements after some specified elements or before them, but i didn't because i thought there's no need to do that, and although i created a class to do it if yourself wants.**

**5 - Write your managing codes in the final for loop in the specified position.**

> Code

```
import os, xml.dom.minidom as dom
from enum import Enum

#-----------------------definePath
containingFolder ="pathToContainingFolder"

files = os.listdir(containingFolder)

#if you want to add before and after specific elements
#then add this future to adding method
class addingPlace():

    class types(Enum):
        Parent = 0
        Above  = 1
        Below  = 2

    def __init__(self, TagName, PlaceType):
        self.TagName = TagName
        self.PlaceType = PlaceType

    def getElement(parser, tagIndex=0):
        return parser.getElementsByTagName(self.TagName)[tagIndex];


#---------------------delete element
def deleteElement(selfTag, parser, tagIndex=0):
    global s;
    try:
        s = parser.getElementsByTagName(selfTag)[tagIndex];
    except:
        print("Error in line 25 (tag name or tag index is invalid)")
        return;
    p = s.parentNode;
    try:
        p.removeChild(s);
    except:
        print("Error in line 27 (parent has no specified child)")


#---------------------add element
def addElement(tagName, parentTagName, parser, elementText=None, parentTagIndex=0):
    element = dom.Element(tagName)

    if(elementText is not None):
        txt = dom.Text()
        txt.data = elementText
        element.childNodes.append(txt)

    try:
        parentElement = parser.getElementsByTagName(parentTagName)[parentTagIndex]
        parentElement.childNodes.append(element)
    except:
        print("Error in line 41 (parent tag name or tag index is invalid)")


#-------------------tranfer element to specified parent
def transferElement(tagName, parentTagName, parser, tagIndex=0, parentTagIndex=0):
    try:
        deleting = parser.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[tagIndex];
    except:
        print("Error in line 47 (tag name or tag index is invalid)")
        return;
    element = deleting.cloneNode(True)
    deleting.parentNode.removeChild(deleting)
    try:
        parentElement = parser.getElementsByTagName(parentTagName)[parentTagIndex]
    except:
        print("Error in line 53 (parent tag name or tag index is invalid)")
    parentElement.childNodes.append(element)



#----------------------usage location

for f in files:
    with open(os.path.join(containingFolder, f), 'r+') as fl:
        fileText = fl.read()
        xmlParsed = dom.parseString(fileText)     #use this as parser
        root = xmlParsed.documentElement.nodeName #use this as root element        

        #there you can use adding and deleting and trans.. methods
        # this is an example:-
        #addElement("C_Type",root,xmlParsed,elementText="ASCI")


        formattedText = xmlParsed.toxml()
        fl.seek(0);
        fl.write(formattedText);
        fl.truncate();
```